# Synchronize any two Javascript objects over Websocket

Tags: javascript, websocket, synchronization

Is there a Javascript library or pattern that will synchronize any two objects over a Websocket connection?

By synchronize I mean copies each property of the object to the remote, and when any property of the object changes on either end, the 'update' is copied to the 'out-of-date' one. Just like any other "two-way synchronization".

Of course it should be able to handle changing bandwidth transparently, and should also be able to synchronize whenever there's a working network connection, even if the last synchronization operation failed (network connectivity lost or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

This can recursively append properties from one object to another, like this:

```
jQuery.extend(true, destinationObject, sourceObject)
```

If changes might also include removal, you need a tree diff algorithm. There should be JavaScript implementations available if you search for them.

If your objects are "flat", you can just do `jQuery.extend(destinationObject, sourceObject)`. It might also be worth looking at underscoreJS, which has functions like `union`, `difference` and `intersection`.

The websocket implementation shouldn't be especially complicated. Just define setters, and maybe add a timeout, so x seconds need to pass since the last change before an upload.